# continuous integration, how to generate a single build(binary) for both QA and App Store release?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

we have a Jenkins CI environment for iOS to generate binaries and sign certificates for QA or App Store release, and want to submit the same binary that QA tested on to App Store.

In xcode, we can generate a archive and sign different certificates to it. e.g. sign adhoc certificate for QA testing. After the testing done, we can submit the same archive to app store by signing the App Store certificate. However, it's manual steps in xcode. Is it possible to automated in Jenkins/CI environment? what is the best way to do this? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You should add a second Xcode build. The first one should generate the app for QA and the second one for the App Store, with a different certificate, then store the App Store version somewhere with version number so you can identify which App Store build relates to which QA build.

Comment: that's what we have now. but we want to have the exact same binary both for QA and App Store. for example, we generate a binary(bin), then sign the adhoc certificate for QA (bin+adhoc certificate); then sign the app store certificate for App store(bin+app store certificate).

Comment: we can have the same archive signing with different certificates. I am looking for the best way to automate this in our CI environment.

Comment: If you already have the scripts for signing then you can use it in Jenkins most likely.